# Stop callback propagation

Tags: php, cakephp, event-handling, cakephp-2.0

I have a Behavior which update a record instead of delete from `beforeDelete` callback.

```
public function beforeDelete(Model $model, $cascade = true) {
    [...]

    return true;
}
```

When I return `true`, the deletion proccess continues, instead of stop. I wan't to stop propagation of next event which is `delete`.

I have read about `stopPropagation()` function of `CakeEvent` but don't know what to do and how to use correctly inside a behavior. May you help-me?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [the CakePHP core libraries help page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#stopping-events):

```
public function beforeDelete(Model $model, $cascade = true,$event) {
    [...]

    $event->stopPropogation();
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Behavior extends `ModelBehavior`, which have the callback defined with only two parameters. I will try with `$model->getEventManager()`.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the deletion you should return *false* in beforeDelete() callback instead of returning *true*.
Check [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html):

> This function should return true if you want the deletion to continue, and false if you want to abort.

So your code should look like this:

```
public function beforeDelete(Model $model, $cascade = true) {
    [...]

    return false;
}
```